# Oracle outer join short hand with upper

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

Works:

```
AND UPPER(a.name) = b.lname(+)
```

does not work

```
AND UPPER(a.name) = UPPER(b.lname) (+)
```

Moving to ANSI joins is an option but a painstaking one. This code should be changed in lot of places and there are lot of joins.  I would like to get this syntax correct and be on my way.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yuck - move to ANSI join format - much nicer and less scope for errors!

Comment: how can this be converted to ANSI?

Comment: Both are ANSI - this is 89 syntax; 92 has outer join support - which this is about, because this question is about Oracle's old-school outer join syntax...

Comment: Doesn't 89 use =* and *= for outer joins?  Filth, regardless.

Comment: @Will A: That's SQL Server old school outer join syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428144/sql-what-does-mean

Comment: @Will: No - SQL-89 did not specify outer joins at all.  Each vendor had their own idiosyncratic and non-standard notation.  The standard notation is at least reasonably clean and uniform across DBMS.  Not all systems support the USING clause that the standard provides; AFAIK, they all provide the ON clause.

Comment: @OMG: the '(+)' notation is specific to Oracle - and only Oracle.  It was never part of SQL-86 or SQL-89.

Comment: @Jonathan - thanks, I guess that explains why Oracle has the seemingly odder syntax.  Thank heavens for SQL-92!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yuckiness aside, incorporating UPPER() with the old skool OUTER JOIN syntax is simplicity itself: we just need to get the brackets in the right order:

```
SQL> select t23.name
  2         , d.university
  3  from t23
  4       , t_doctors d
  5  where upper(t23.name) = upper(d.name(+))
  6  order by t23.id
  7  /

NAME         UNIVERSITY
------------ --------------------
SAM-I-AM
MR KNOX
FOX IN SOCKS
CAT
LORAX
BILLY
MAISIE
DR SINATRA   Whoville U
DR FONZ      U of Grin-itch
PINNER BLINN

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Here is how to deploy the newer syntax with multiple tables:

```
SQL> select t23.name
  2         , d.university
  3         , k.school
  4  from t23
  5       left outer join t_doctors d
  6                  on upper(t23.name) = upper(d.name)
  7       left outer join t_kids k
  8                  on upper(t23.name) = upper(k.name)
  9  order by t23.id
 10  /

NAME         UNIVERSITY           SCHOOL
------------ -------------------- --------------------
SAM-I-AM                          Mulberry St Junior
MR KNOX
FOX IN SOCKS
CAT
LORAX
BILLY                             Roover River High
MAISIE                            Roover River High
DR SINATRA   Whoville U
DR FONZ      U of Grin-itch
PINNER BLINN

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: +1: Interesting, I hope I never have to remember the trick though :)

Comment: does adding UPPER mean that index will not be used? I know indexes are not used if we add trim

Comment: @learn_plsql - that's a separate question ;)  The short answer is you're correct, but there are workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

<s>It is quite possible that the second version of the code will not work, ever.  If it wasn't in use before, it is all the more plausible that it won't work.</s> (See the accepted answer for how to use the obsolesent notation.  I still think that the rest of the advice below stands - but note carefully the qualifier '*when you need to modify the SQL*'; if you don't need to change the SQL for some other reason, there's no necessity to remove the old-style notation.)

Bite the bullet and deal with the ANSI join when you need to do the case-insensitive comparison.  Or investigate a locale-based alternative (with case-insensitive comparisons), if such an option exists in Oracle.

Fundamentally, though, you should consign the old '(+)' outer join notation to the trash can.  When you have to modify an SQL statement, remove the old (obsolescent) notation and use the ANSI join notation instead.

---

A comment asks 'how can this be converted to ANSI'?

You rewrite the FROM clause as well as the WHERE clause - often moving join conditions from the WHERE clause to the ON conditions in the FROM clause.

```
 SELECT a.*, b.*
   FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON UPPER(a.name) = UPPER(b.lname)
```

---

Another comment asks 'how to extend the join to three tables'?

```
 SELECT a.*, b.*
   FROM a 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON UPPER(a.name) = UPPER(b.lname)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON on a.first = c.first
```

Comment: what if a needs to be outer joined with another table , say, c. then do we do ? `FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON UPPER(a.name) = UPPER(b.name), a LEFT OUTER JOIN c on a.first = c.first`

Comment: "It is quite possible that the second version of the code will not work, ever." - actually it does work, with the correct placement of brackets.

Comment: I too prefer the new skool outer joins too, but there are good reasons for using the `(+)` notation. Not the least of which is that Oracle 8i (not to mention earlier versions) remains in widespread use, even if it is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND UPPER(a.name) = UPPER(b.lname (+))
```

Works. I tested it. It is working fine.