# what is the meaning of the operator *=?

Tags: sql, business-intelligence, data-migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: What does =* mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428144/sql-what-does-mean)

Hi all

I got a design someone made and he stated the following on one of the SQLs:

Select * from table_A, table_B
Where
table_A.ID *= table_B.ID

Can anyone tell what does '*=' operator stands for?

Thanks.

Comment: deprecated outer join syntax. this is a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

That is equivalent to a left join in mySql.  It's just on older (weirder) syntax.

It's the same as this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_A
LEFT JOIN table_B
ON table_A.ID = table_B.ID
```