# The SQL Server '=*' operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query which contains something like:

```
select ....
where table1.id =* table2.id
```

What does the '=*' operator  do exactly?

Comment: It doesn't solve your problem for you, but I know the problems you have when searching for symbols in Google. On www.symbolhound.com, you can easily search for things like 'Oracle =*', and it will not drop the operator characters.

Comment: See [Outer Joins: Joining Tables on Columns Containing NULL Values](http://etutorials.org/SQL/sql+bible/Part+IV+Retrieving+and+Transforming+Data/Chapter+9+Multitable+Queries/Outer+Joins+Joining+Tables+on+Columns+Containing+NULL+Values/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip 0xCAFEBABE! Google wasn't yielding any decent search results. And it appears to be a SQL Server operator! Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428144/what-does-mean

Answer (score 5):

=* is shorthand way of writing RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

Vishal is correct, =* is a shorthand, but is not ansi standard and generally not the recommended way of doing joins and have been deprecated.

It will work, and is relatively readable when you only have a couple of tables but as soon as you starting adding it more tables it quickly becomes hard to read.

Good to know what it means, but also good to avoid.

Comment: I totally disagree on the "relatively readable".  I, for one, can never remember if these constructs are for `left outer join` or `right outer join`.

Comment: It will work in SQL Server 2000 and older only. In versions 2005 and 2008 it produces warning and it can work with compatibility level set to 80 (sql2000) or lower. In SQL Server 2012 it is incorrect syntax and can't work.