# SQL old outer join conversion; operator =* is not supported in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Please help me convert this query to SQL Server 2012. The operator `=*` is not supported in SQL Server 2012:

```
select 
    Sum(ISNULL(Qty_Recd,0.00)) as Qty_Recd, a.PR_Detail_Key
from 
    PO_Dely c, PO_Tracking1 a
where 
    c.PO_Key =* a.PO_Key 
    and PR_No = '123456' 
    and a.File_Type = 72 
    and c.File_Type = 72
group by 
    a.PR_Detail_Key 
order by 
    a.PR_Detail_Key
```

Comment: see link from accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428144/what-does-mean)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to move to explicit join syntax.  Try this:

```
select 
    Sum(ISNULL(Qty_Recd,0.00)) as Qty_Recd
    , a.PR_Detail_Key 
from PO_Dely as c
    right outer join PO_Tracking1 as a 
        on c.PO_Key = a.PO_Key 
where PR_No = '123456' 
    and a.File_Type = 72 
    and c.File_Type = 72 
group by a.PR_Detail_Key 
order by a.PR_Detail_Key
```

Comment: Post sample data, then.  Also, please note that I got the direction wrong initially - "=*" is a right outer join.  I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Brian, All `WHERE` conditions should be moved to `ON`

Comment: Thanks @Brian & Alex, it's works with below changes,  select 
    Sum(ISNULL(Qty_Recd,0.00)) as Qty_Recd
    , a.PR_Detail_Key 
from [ePR].[dbo].PO_Dely as c
    Right outer join [ePR].[dbo].PO_Tracking1 as a 
        on c.PO_Key = a.PO_Key 
 and a.File_Type = 72 
    and c.File_Type = 72 
where PR_No = 'PR-00149964' 
    group by a.PR_Detail_Key 
order by a.PR_Detail_Key

Comment: @Alex, I've always put conditions like (for example) "a.File_Type = 72" in the WHERE clause.  If there are objective reasons why it should be part of the JOIN, I would love to learn them.

Comment: @Karthik, I'm glad we could help.  I would still love to see some sample data so that I can wrap my brain around why moving the File_Type comparisons to the JOIN clause made it work, if you're of a mind to share.

Comment: @Brian, it is a right join, if you put **all** conditions into `WHERE` is stops working as a right join. You should be able to keep a.File_Type = 72 in `WHERE` though.

Comment: @Alex, I just had a light go on.  I deal almost exclusively with `Inner Join`; my lack of practical experience with `Outer Join` probably explains my ignorance in this area.  Thanks for making time to explain that.